# New Duplicated Rows with Pandas and BeautifulSoup Scraper

Tags: pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I have build a Scraper on top of Politifact website. A non profit organisation that rates the veracity of news in the United States. I have retrieved a total of 18066 URLS to news ratings from which I want scrape some information. Somehow after the code has executed I have a total of 41666 news ratings stored in a .csv file, some duplicates have appeared. Here is my code

```
#Get links from CSV file
urls = []
with open(f'{PATH}ULR_list.csv', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.read().split(',')

num_urls = len(urls)
print(f'There is total of {num_urls} URLS')

#Final DataFrame
df  = pd.read_csv(f'{PATH}politifactDataset.csv')
count = 0

for u in urls:
    dic = {}

    #Construct Link
    link = 'https://www.politifact.com'+u.replace('"','')

    #Request
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    #Get Title
    title_ = soup.select('.m-statement__content .m-statement__quote')
    title = title_[0].text.replace('\n','')
    dic['Title'] = title

    #Get Tags
    tags_ = soup.select('.m-list.m-list--horizontal .m-list__item')
    tags = ''
    for t in tags_:
        tags += t.select_one('span').text + ','
    dic['Tags'] = tags

    #Get Author
    author_ = soup.select(".m-statement__author .m-statement__name")
    author = author_[0].text.replace('\n','')
    dic['Author'] = author

    #Get Rating
    rating_ = soup.select(".m-statement__body .m-statement__meter [alt]")
    rating = rating_[0]['alt']
    dic['Rating'] = rating

    #Save into DataFrame
    df = df.append(dic, ignore_index=True)

    
    count += 1
    if count%100 == 0:
        #time.sleep(3)
        percentage = (count/num_urls)*100
        print(f'{percentage}%')
        df.to_csv('politifactDataset.csv', index = False)

df.to_csv('politifactDataset.csv', index = False)
```

> There is total of 18066 URLS

If I open the .csv file

```
df = pd.read_csv('politifactDataset.csv')
length = len(df)
print(f'There is a total of {length} rows')
```

> There is a total of 41666 rows

I know I can use `df.drop_duplicates` but some duplicates still remain. My question is **Where are this duplicated rows coming from?**

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of what's inside `ULR_list.csv`?

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code. I've solved by saving the data frame only once, when all URLS are scraped.

```
#Get links from CSV file
urls = []
with open(f'{PATH}ULR_list.csv', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.read().split(',')

num_urls = len(urls)
print(f'There is total of {num_urls} URLS')

#Final DataFrame
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title','Tags','Author','Rating'])

for u in urls:
    dic = {}

    #Construct Link
    link = 'https://www.politifact.com'+u.replace('"','')

    #Request
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    #Get Title
    title_ = soup.select('.m-statement__content .m-statement__quote')
    title = title_[0].text.replace('\n','')
    dic['Title'] = title

    #Get Tags
    tags_ = soup.select('.m-list.m-list--horizontal .m-list__item')
    tags = ''
    for t in tags_:
        tags += t.select_one('span').text + ','
    dic['Tags'] = tags

    #Get Author
    author_ = soup.select(".m-statement__author .m-statement__name")
    author = author_[0].text.replace('\n','')
    dic['Author'] = author

    #Get Rating
    rating_ = soup.select(".m-statement__body .m-statement__meter [alt]")
    rating = rating_[0]['alt']
    dic['Rating'] = rating

    #Save into DataFrame
    df = df.append(dic, ignore_index=True)

    
    if len(df)%1000 == 0:
        percentage = (len(df)/num_urls)*100
        print(f'{percentage}%')

df.to_csv('politifactDataset.csv', index = False)
```